# What is this pink or blue colored flower with a white ring in the center?

Tags: identification, flowers

I saw it my friend's album. What is this flower?

<sub>(Click to enlarge)</sub>
[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps ask your friend where he took this photo? If it's online (Flickr/Picasa), it might have the location info on it...

Comment: Somewhere in Australia.

Comment: ah cool, thanks. That will help folks a lot in identifying, because Australia has very strict laws on what can be brought in and not. As such, it is possible that it might be native there.

Answer (score 4):

My guess:

- [*Pericallis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pericallis)

And as certain as I can (dare) be:

- [Florist's cineraria *(Pericallis x hybrida)*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=B563)
- [Florist's cineraria *(Pericallis cruenta)*](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/54084/)